# How do I successfully submit a Facebook App Review for a server-to-server App?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've written a Python script to pull performance metrics data from the Facebook Graph API for a connected Instagram Business account. It's a script which runs locally and uses my account's credentials.

I've submitted an App Review selecting **"No"** and **"App doesn't use the Facebook Login dialog."** for the **"Is a Facebook reviewer able to access or login to your app to verify you're using permissions or features according to Facebook Platform Policy?"** and **"Why isn't a Facebook reviewer able to access or install your app? Select the option(s) that best describe the functionality of your integration."** questions.

However, it's been rejected with the following reason given:
"We found that your app's test credentials did not allow us to fully review the content of the app or there were no test credentials provided for us to review. If your test credentials do allow access, check that the account is setup properly to provide us with full access and to allow us to reproduce the use case steps."

I followed the steps from the [Server-to-Server App Sample Submission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-review/resources/sample-submissions/server-to-server). I've explained why each permission is required and uploaded a screencast of accessing the relevant endpoints.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: The reviewers don’t always get it right on the first try … Can only suggest that you submit again. Be as explicit as you can in your review instructions, for them to “grasp” what type of app it is.